# Right Click + New XLSX Workbook Results In "Excel cannot open the file because the file format or extension is not valid."

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, file-extension

Lately I have been having an issue that seems to have happened quite out of the blue where if I go into a folder from File Explorer to create a new .xlsx workbook using a right-click I will create a 0kb file and then I receive an error message that says:

`Excel cannot open the file 'name.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.`

Oddly enough, if I open Excel directly and work in a .xlsx file and save it, then I can reopen that file later on. So it seems like I have all the sudden lost the functionality of being able to right-click open a new .xlsx document. If I try to do this exact same thing with a .docx file though, everything works as expected.

**What have I done so far?**

- I have opened Excel and have gone `properties -> security` and made sure permissions are set to Full Control.
- I have checked that the file format that I am opening is indeed .xlsx and not something else.

Unfortunately most of what I have tried to find online does not seem to be helping, so I needed something a bit more interactive.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Excel app, then create the .xlsx file, close it then open it, would it be opened correctly?

I would suggest you go to Registry Editor, then locate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xlsx\Excel.Sheet.12\ShellNew`, then check the data value for "FileName", make sure its pathe is pointed to one .xlsx file.

The screenshot is taken from my enviornment with Microsoft 365 apps (64 bit).

[image]

If it is not a .xlsx worksheet, please create a blank worksheet in Excel instead of right-clicking. Then point the data value to it.